# How can I set up a React Router auth flow?

Tags: authentication, react-router, graphql

I'm new to React and having trouble creating a simple auth flow using GraphQL, following the React Router example.

I would like `/` to be my login screen, which appears only if the user is logged out.  If not, the app should redirect to `/dashboard` (which should otherwise be inaccessible).  Here's what I have, which generates an infinite loop after authentication:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            authenticated: false
        }
    }

    renderButtons () {
        if (this.state.authenticated) {
            return (
                <a>Logout</a>
            )
        }
        return null;
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps({ data }) {
        if (this.props.data.loading && !data.loading) {
            if (data.loggedInUser.id && !this.state.authenticated) {
                this.setState({authenticated: true});
            } else if (this.state.authenticated) {
                this.setState({authenticated: false});
            }
        }
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <nav>
                    {this.renderButtons()}
                </nav>
                <GatingRoute path="/" component={LoginPage} isAuthenticated={this.state.authenticated} newPath="/dashboard" />
                <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} isAuthenticated={this.state.authenticated} />
            </div>
        );
    }
};

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest}) => (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => (
        isAuthenticated
        ? (
           <Component {...props} />
        )
        : (<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} />)
      )}
    />
    );

const GatingRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, newPath, ...rest}) => (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => (
        isAuthenticated
        ? (
            (<Redirect to={{ pathname: newPath, state: { from: props.location } }} />)
        )
        : 
        <Component {...props} />
      )}
    />
    );

export default graphql(query, { options: {fetchPolicy: 'network-only'}})(withRouter(App));
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than working the way you are now...

In your parent component where you have your routes do the following

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route path=“/“ exact         render={ ( props ) =>
 props.user.loggedIn ? <Dashboard /> : <LoginForm />
}/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

This assumes the component that renders your router knows of the user status.

My apologies for the poor formatting on mobile.

Comment: This didn't actually work for me because I'm not sure how to get the authentication prop from the parent object to the Route.  However, you inspired this approach with dynamic JSX, which did work:

    `renderRoute () {
        if (this.state.authenticated) {
            return (
                <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard}/>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <Route exact path="/" component={LoginForm}/>
            )
        }
    }`

Comment: Long as you found a method that works for you I’m happy.